# How to use `sqlcmd` command without username and password in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, sqlcmd

How can I run commands, passed to `sqlcmd`, as currently logged on user automatically i.e without having to enter username and password?

I want to use Windows Authentication only. It is a local server.

Comment: can you set up a scheduled task to run as a specific user?  If so, I think the -E argument with sqlcmd is what you are looking for.

Comment: Solution: go to Google, search for `SQL Server SQLCMD`, pick the first link which leads you to the [**official MSDN documentation** for `SQLCMD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), read the docs, see that you need to use `-E` for integrated security - was that so hard?

Comment: @marc_s it does imply that you know that Windows Authentication == Integrated Security == Trusted Connection, which is not necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sqlcmd` takes the `-E` argument, which means, "Use Trusted Connection"... IOW, your windows credentials.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx