# 'sqlcmd' utility unable to login to the database

Tags: sql, sqlcmd

I have a large `.sql` data file (4.3 GB) and I would like to execute this file on `SQL Server`. Doing some research, I found that I can execute this file using the following command:

```
sqlcmd -U username -P password -S rs-reporting-v1 -d NSTest  -i D:NetSuiteDataFiles\Transactions.sql -o D:\NetSuiteDataFiles\Transactions_output_file.txt
```

When I execute the above command, get the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I've tried changing the `username` to `domain\username` but it didn't help at all. I have checked the spellings of `username` and `password` multiple times and I'm sure they're correct.

**EDIT**

I changed my command to the following:

```
sqlcmd -E -S rs-reporting-v2 -d NSTest  -i D:NetSuiteDataFil
es\Transactions.sql -o D:\NetSuiteDataFiles\Transactions_output_file.txt
```

and now I get the following error:

[image]

Would someone please be able to let me know what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

I would also like to point out that the `.sql` file is creating a table and then inserting values.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701829/sqlcmd-command-without-username-and-password-in-sql-server-2008 help?

Comment: This is almost certainly due to having the wrong server and/or instance name.  Are you trying to connect to a named instance?  Are you able to connect to the server specified via SSMS?  Also, have you looked into BCP, which might be better for bulk importing data?

Comment: I was under the impression that `bcp` only inserts data (please correct me if I'm wrong), but my `.sql` file is creating table and then inserting data. Yes, I'm able to connect to the server using SSMS.